# Solr Query Performance

Tags: solr

We are using solr 4.3 for search funcationlity. We have configured 2 shard and 2 replicas.

We have total 132905 Solr documents in index.

Our search query is very long takes around 3 second (from Solr Admin Console) for below query.

id:(FOLD5002861 FOLD5002890 FOLD5219963 FOLD4105003 FOLD4105005 FOLD4105006 FOLD4105007 FOLD4105008 FOLD4105009 FOLD4105010 FOLD4105011 FOLD4105012 FOLD4105013 FOLD4105014 FOLD4105018 FOLD4105019 FOLD4105020 FOLD4105021 FOLD4105022 FOLD4105023 FOLD4105024 FOLD4105025 FOLD4105026 FOLD4105027 FOLD5220166 FOLD5220168 FOLD5220169 FOLD5220170 FOLD5220171 FOLD5220172 FOLD5220173 FOLD5220174 FOLD5220175 FOLD5220176 FOLD5220177 FOLD5220178 FOLD5220179 FOLD5220180 FOLD5220181 FOLD4100876 FOLD4100877 FOLD4100878 FOLD4100879 FOLD4100880 FOLD4100881 FOLD4655426 FOLD4655428 FOLD4655429 FOLD4655430 FOLD4655431 FOLD4655432 FOLD4655433 FOLD4655434 FOLD4655435 FOLD4655436 FOLD4655437 FOLD4655438 FOLD4655439 FOLD4655483 FOLD4655487 FOLD4655523 FOLD4655874 FOLD4655884 FOLD4655856 FOLD4655858 FOLD4655859 FOLD4655860 FOLD4655861 FOLD4655862 FOLD4655863 FOLD4655864 FOLD4655865 FOLD4655866 FOLD4655867 FOLD4655868 FOLD4655869 FOLD4655870 FOLD4655871 FOLD4655872 FOLD4655882 FOLD4655892 FOLD4649510 FOLD4649512 FOLD4649513 FOLD4649514 FOLD4649515...50000 times)

We want to trace where it is taking time. we tried debugQuery option in solr Admin console but not getting useful information.

Is there any way to improve the query? How can we track detail timing?

Comment: Can you convert this field into numeric only?Can you do range queries? Try putting this field into the field cache (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#fieldcache).

Answer (score 0):

If you transform this query into a filter query it will give better performance most of the time because it will apply the filter on top of a query (that is a subset of your index and that can be cached) and not on the entire index.

The best would be if you had another piece of query that you could run with this and then apply this as a filter on top of that , but if you donøt have it also running a query for `field:[* TO *]` should still give better performances.

have a look at this question that explain the difference between filter query and normal query:

[SOLR filter-query vs main-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730898/solr-filter-query-vs-main-query)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [some factors that affect Solr performance](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors).

Try to optimize your index with:

```
curl http://<solr_host>:<port>/solr/<core_name>/update -F stream.body=' <optimize />'
```