# Search with multiple parameters in solr

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

Currently I having the query like this

```
q=mysearchparameters
```

It is working fine, and I think it will search for this keyword in all the fields, now I want to retrieve data only based in some specific field like this

```
q=name:'somename'+specialization:'somespecialization'
```

is it possible to query like, here I getting some unexpected datas for my second query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple queries, ANDed together, like this:

```
q=name:somename AND specialization:somespecialization
```

or ORer together like this:

```
q=name:somename OR specialization:somespecialization
```

Or you can use filter queries to AND them together:

```
q=*:*&fq=name:somename&fq=specialization:somespecialization
```

I won't get into queries versus filter queries as it is covered better elsewhere:

[SOLR filter-query vs main-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730898/solr-filter-query-vs-main-query)

Answer (score 2):

in order to perform a multicriteria request, you'd better do :

```
q=*:*
fq= name:*somename* 
fq= specialization:*specializstr*


http req example : http://localhost:8983/solr/datav6/select?q=*%3A*&fq=data%3A*carlos*%5E5&fq=entity%3Aemployee&wt=json&indent=true
```

it' saffer on the results, faster on execution and consumes less ram. 
enjoy and give me some feedback please! :)

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy solr