# Solr: Query both Parent and Child docs

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4j

Using Solr:5.5.3, Java 7.

I have to fetch all **Item:Cap and Size_s:XL, With facets: COLOR_s and SIZE_s**.
Here Item is part of Parent Doc and Size is part of Child doc. I have thought of using BlockJoin but i am not able to understand how to Query both parent and child at the same time.

Would appreciate any help and guidance. Thanks.

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">1</field>
    <field name="type_s">forSaleItem</field>
    <field name="item">Shirt</field>
    <doc>
      <field name="id">11</field>
      <field name="type_s">itemAttrDoc</field>
      <field name="COLOR_s">Red</field>
      <field name="SIZE_s">XL</field>
      <field name="PRICE_i">6</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="type_s">itemAttrDoc</field>
      <field name="id">12</field>
      <field name="COLOR_s">Red</field>
      <field name="SIZE_s">XL</field>
      <field name="PRICE_i">7</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="type_s">itemAttrDoc</field>
      <field name="id">13</field>
      <field name="COLOR_s">Blue</field>
      <field name="SIZE_s">L</field>
      <field name="PRICE_i">5</field>
    </doc>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">2</field>
    <field name="type_s">forSaleItem</field>
    <field name="item">Cap</field>
    <doc>
      <field name="type_s">itemAttrDoc</field>
      <field name="id">21</field>
      <field name="COLOR_s">Blue</field>
      <field name="SIZE_s">XL</field>
      <field name="PRICE_i">6</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="type_s">itemAttrDoc</field>
      <field name="id">22</field>
      <field name="COLOR_s">Blue</field>
      <field name="SIZE_s">XL</field>
      <field name="PRICE_i">7</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="type_s">itemAttrDoc</field>
      <field name="id">23</field>
      <field name="COLOR_s">Red</field>
      <field name="SIZE_s">L</field>
      <field name="PRICE_i">5</field>
    </doc>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">3</field>
    <field name="type_s">NotforSaleItem</field>
    <field name="item">trouser</field>
    <doc>
      <field name="type_s">itemAttrDoc</field>
      <field name="id">21</field>
      <field name="COLOR_s">Blue</field>
      <field name="SIZE_s">XL</field>
      <field name="PRICE_i">6</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="type_s">itemAttrDoc</field>
      <field name="id">22</field>
      <field name="COLOR_s">Blue</field>
      <field name="SIZE_s">XL</field>
      <field name="PRICE_i">7</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <field name="type_s">itemAttrDoc</field>
      <field name="id">23</field>
      <field name="COLOR_s">Red</field>
      <field name="SIZE_s">L</field>
      <field name="PRICE_i">5</field>
    </doc>
  </doc>
</add>
```

**Edit**:
type_s identifies the docs, So any query should also contain this field.

Comment: You'll probably find the answer to your question in the [Solr Block Join Parser Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
q={!parent which="Item:Cap"}Size_s:XL&facet.field=SIZE_s&facet.field=COLOR_s&facet=on
```

This should give you the documents that you need.

I've used [Solr Block Join Parser Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers) and [yonik's Solr Nested Objects Tutorial](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.

Believe it or not i have written exact query that you provided and i am referring to same link references. 

Now, i have to query the parent doc by item and also **type_s**, apologise for not mentioning it in my question, this is what i am trying to address now. 


I might have more fields of parent **and** child docs i need to match with.



As i see, i can repeat the query you mentioned. Trying it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003195/solr-block-join-parent-query-with-many-children-constraints