# Solr - Querying on nested child documents

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a requirement where in a parent document has two child documents . For example , the doc which is indexed looks like this ,

```
{
"id":123,
"name":"nithin",
"_childDocuments_":[
{
"id":"22"
"place":"blr",
"parent_id":123,
"street":"inagar"
},
{
"id":"23"
"place":"tvm",
"parent_id":123,
"street":"bakery"
}
]
}
```

Here the name - nithin has two child documents with distinct place and street . My requirement is to query for all parents with a specific place and/or street .
Lets say blr and bakery. If i fire a query saying (blr and bakery) it would not return any results . I cant use blr or bakery because i want a parent document for which the child docs should have blr and bakery . How do i achieve this ?

Comment: Answer is found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003195/solr-block-join-parent-query-with-many-children-constraints

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve your goal is through [Block Join Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers) capabilities.

What you need change a little bit - is to introduce some marker for parent documents. In Solr glossary it will be needed for "parent filter". So assuming each parent document will have `content_type:parentDocument` (just for sake of example) you'll be able to find all your parent documents with BJQ (block-join query) like:

```
{!parent which="content_type:parentDocument"}(+place:blr +street:bakery)
```

Please bear in mind you need to index your parent-children documents together (in the same block) as described on [Solr wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers) (but as I see you already doing so, I guess it should be good to go).

Comment: This would not work as this basically queries for a single child document which has place as blr or street as bakery and corresponding parents are returned . What i need is parents for which both place and street is blr or bakery , which means blr can appear in one child document and bakery in another child document . To make it short , i need a parent only if he has two sons . For ex: if i search for Abel AND Cain i should get only Adam , eventhough Adam1 and Adam2 may have Abel or Cain and not both

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. I bet Solr doesn't have out-of-the-box plugin. My suggestion is trying to make fake child and put all field values there. Seems ugly, I know but it works.

Comment: Yeah basically having only one child document per parent with the values for each field clubbed together as an array . That would solve this , but that would get rid of the correlation between fields , Was thinking of something like this , q = (Abel OR Cain)&facet=true&facet.field=parent_id&facet.mincount=2 . This would give me all the parent_ids which has Abel and Cain as children . And programatically i can count the number of elements in the facet array returned . Does it make sense ?